# How to sort by Array index on Mongoose using a variable instead of string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, sorting

### I'm trying to sort my data based on the index value of a variable.

I want to have `totalClicks[0]`, but the `totalClicks[0]` syntax don't work. I've searched and tried using `'totalClicks.0'`, which works fine. But I need to check the `req.params.bossId` to sort the data based on the `array[req.params.bossId]`.

**This first**, hardcoded, code works.

```
User.find({}).sort({ 'totalClicks.0' : '1'}).exec(
  function (err, data) {
    res.json(data);
});
```

**This code**, which dynamically selects which array field to sort, don't work and the whole .sort method gets ignored.

```
var bossId = req.params.bossId;
var totalClicksId = 'totalClicks.' + bossId;

console.log(totalClicksId);           // totalClicks.0
console.log(typeof(totalClicksId));   // string

User.find({}).sort({ totalClicksId : '1'}).exec(
  function (err, data) {
    res.json(data);
  });
```

If the `ID` variable is `0`, them I want to sort the data by `totalClicks[0]`. 
If the `ID` variable is `1`, them I want to sort the data by `totalClicks[1]`.

**I need to receive a variable `bossId` and, using that variable, sort my data based on the `array[bossId]`. How could I do that?**

> Appendix:

**Model:**

```
[
  {
    "username": "p",
    "totalClicks": [
      67,
      25
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "kk",
    "totalClicks": [
      61,
      38
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set an objects keys with a variable containing a string literally like that, and your sort function basically takes an object as it's argument.

```
.sort({key : value})
```

to create an object with dynamic keys, we have to do

```
var obj = {};
var key = 'something';

obj[key] = 'value'; // now obj === {'something' : 'value'}
```

So the solution is to create the object first, then pass it in

```
var totalClicksId = 'totalClicks.' + req.params.bossId;

var obj = {};

obj[totalClicksId] = '1';

User.find({}).sort(obj).exec(function (err, data) {
   res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: I think I did not explain it correctly. I want to sort my array based on the ID index of the totalClicks array. If ID=0, them I want to sort by totalClicks[0], if ID=1, them by totalClicks[1].

Comment: I've tried your answer already. Like this: `var bossId = req.params.bossId;
    var totalClicks = {};
    totalClicks[bossId] = -1;
    User.find({}).sort(totalClicks).exec(` but it did not worked. The sort gets ignored. I've made anything wrong?

Comment: That doesn't give you the same output as the code above, you'd end up with an object looking something like this `sort({"0" : -1})` ?

Comment: `var bossId = 'totalClicks.' + req.params.bossId`; you supposed to be like this

Comment: Did not see that line. Thank you very much, @adeneo. It worked!